# JSESSIONID cookie not stored

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a frontend written in angular which runs on localhost:3002.
I have a backend written with Spring-boot which runs on localhost:8080.

I added a filter to handle CORS (which I found on SO and adapted to my need) :

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3002");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

When I authenticate, I can see that the server sends a cookie :

[image]

This cookie is not sent with the following requests. This results in 401 responses :

[image]

I looked at the "resources" panel of the chrome console and found out that no cookie were stored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file where you configure your `$httpProvider`, add this line to specify you want to send credentials with cross-site requests:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Typically, AngularJS will automatically send these cookies with requests (for same-origin requests) but since your requests are cross-site then you have to manually configure this.