# Response return set-cookie, Angular don't store it

Tags: angular, spring-security, angular-cli, session-cookies

I'm using Angular HttpClient.

When I make a login request to my spring-boot API my request returns a cookie with `JSESSIONID` that should be stored in the browser.

The cookie is stored when I build my angular app and place the generated files in my spring (backend) folder and run it along.

When I debug my Angular app in development, the cookie is not stored in my browser.

It might be related, I'm using angular-cli proxy to avoid CORS problems between my client and server:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "https://localhost:8443",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

set-cookie received in response header:

```
set-cookie:JSESSIONID=1F16D001A85DDD17CE840CF2A3694231;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
```

**My Question**

Why the cookie is not stored in my angular development environment although the browser sends a send-cookie in the request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSESSIONID cookie not stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078846/jsessionid-cookie-not-stored)